# .htaccess error's not working as intended

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, error-handling

I have several `.php` pages which I use URL rewriting for, and I have one page which I'm not using url rewriting for.

In my `.htaccess` file I've written the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404   /Reducation/Aarde/errors/404.php
```

This works for the one page which I'm **not** using URL rewriting for.

However when I visit a page with URL rewriting and incorrectly type the url, like: `http://localhost/Reducation/Log-in/Regi`
It displays the standard XAMPP 404 error, instead of my custom one, is there any way to solve this or is there anyway to disable the standard XAMPP 404 message?

This is the error message displayed, along with the regular `Object not found`:

```
Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6
```

I've tried the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404   /Reducation/Log-in/errors/404.php
"ErrorDocument 404   /Reducation/Log-in/errors/404.php"
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

My [source](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/change-error-documents.html).

Edit: My assumption is that it doesn't work when I rewrite the url because the paths don't match up to `errors`

I've just tested out what I believed it to be, and it seems that I'm correct, it doesn't work because the paths don't match. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable xampp 404 custom handler use this line as first line in your root htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404   default
```

404 URI must be absolute, I.e. either it must start with `http://` or a / making it relative from DocumentRoot and exact same URL must work in the browser if entered directly.

Comment: Sir, I would like to disable the default error 404 and use my own, it doesn't work because the paths of the rules don't match

Comment: First test whether it disables default 404 or not.

Comment: Yes it does disable the custom 404, and it forces the page to show the default 404

Comment: So that already answers your question. Now clearly tell what 404 directive isn't working? Make sure exact same URL works from browser.

Comment: I don't want to disable the custom 404.

What I want is this: a custom 404 page which works with URL rewriting

At this moment it only works with static urls which match the document path, I would like for it to work regardless of the document path

Comment: Read your question again where you asked `or is there anyway to disable the standard XAMPP 404 message?` Also about using your custom URI as 404 handler I have already explained how to test.

Comment: That's true, my apologies, testing is going alright, but the problem is that I'm not sure if it's possible to give a 404 error without being document path dependent

Comment: Yes a,404 URI must be absolute, I.e. either it must start with http:// or a / making it relative from DocumentRoot and exact same URL must work in the browser if entered directly.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my assumptions, could you post that in your answer so that I may accept it?